# Find Nth number from a sorted array formed by multiplying any two or more consecutive natural numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, subset, product

I recently encountered this problem:

> There is a (increasingly) sorted array formed by multiplying any two or more consecutive natural numbers.
>
> ```
> 2, 6, 12, 20, 24, 30, 42, 56, 60, 72 ...
> ```
>
> Ex. 2 is formed by two consecutive natural numbers 1 and 2: 2 = 1×2. And 6 = 2×3 OR 1×2×3, 20 = 4×5.
>
> If *n* is given as a parameter, find the *n*th number from the above array and return.
>
> **Limitation**
>
> - 1 ≤ *n* ≤ 1000000
> - *n* is given only when the answer is smaller than 10<sup>12</sup>

So here I was able to find O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) solution, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

My O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) JS solution:

```js
function solution(n) {
    // Find all possible product subsets of [1, ..., n] = [1x2, 2x3, 4x5, ..., 1x2x...xn]
    // return Nth index of this product subset array

    // 1 ~ n+1 array
    const nums = Array.from({ length: n+1 }, (_, i) => i + 1);
    const set = new Set();

    // Find all possible product subsets
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        let accu = 1;
        for (let j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
            accu *= nums[j];
            if (i !== j) set.add(accu);
        }
    }

    // Sort and return n-1 index value
    return Array.from(set).sort((a,b) => a - b)[n-1];
}
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+6%2C+12%2C+20%2C+24%2C+30%2C+42%2C+56%2C+60%2C+72&language=english

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks :) But it only has Pari/GP code...whoa!

Comment: Why are you going up to n in the loop? The constraints say n is only up to one million, which means the multiplicands are less than 1000.

Comment: I understand that `n` corresponds to a multiplicand @גלעדברקן

Comment: @Damien no, n corresponds to a multiple.

Comment: It is a question of terminology I guess. Sorry if my English is bad. We are looking for the `nth` term, and this term is roughly equal to `n(n+1)`. For `n=10^6`, the result is equal to 977410038240. @גלעדברקן

Comment: @Damien but is the number you're suggesting (about n(n+1) achieved by multiplying two numbers only? I thought it would be achieved by multiplying more than two numbers in the range (1, sqrt(n)).

Comment: It appears that a large majority of found numbers (not all of course) are of the form `k(k+1)`. Not sure it corresponds to your concern. @גלעדברקן

Comment: @Damien my point is that k (any one multiplicand) will not exceed sqrt(n), which is why I asked OP why they implemented a loop up to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implementation is based on a min-heap (`std::priority_queue` in C++), that memorizes the "best" future candidates.

One important point is to treat the basic solutions `k *(k+1)` differently. As it is likely that these numbers are in the majority, this allows to greatly reduce the size of the heap.

At each given time, we either decide to use a `k(k+1)`number, or to use the current top value of the min-heap.
Each used value led to insertion of a new candidate in the min-heap.

Another aspect is to only insert in the heap the values less then the estimated max value, `n(n+1)`.

The complexity is estimated to be O(n log M), where M is the mean size of the heap.

For `n = 10^6`, the programme measures that the maximum size of the heap is equal to 9998, much less than `n`.

On my PC, I get the result for `n = 10^6` in 11 ms. Result: 977410038240

Here is the C++ code.

This code memorizes all the sequence, mainly for debugging. In practice, if we only need the nth value, such memorization can be avoided. The measurement of the maximum heap (useful for debugging) size can be removed too, if efficiency is still a concern.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

template <typename T>
void print (const std::vector<T> &A , const std::string &s = "") {
    std::cout << s;
    for (const T& val: A) {
            std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

struct Prod {
    long long p;    // product
    int last;       // last integer in the product
};

long long int consecutive_products (int n) {
    std::vector<long long> products;        // not strictly needed, for debugging
    products.reserve(n);
    products.push_back (2); products.push_back (6);
    
    long long max_val = (long long) n * (n+1);
    
    auto comp = [] (const Prod& x1, const Prod& x2) {
        if (x1.p == x2.p) return x1.last > x2.last;
        return x1.p > x2.p;
    };
    std::priority_queue<Prod, std::vector<Prod>, decltype(comp)> candidates(comp);
    if (n <= 2) return products[n-1];
    candidates.push ({24, 4});      // 2*3*4 -> extension of 2*3
    
    long long int prod_simple = 12; // = 3*4 - simple products k(k-1) are dealt with differently
    int rank_simple = 4;
    
    int index = 2;
    long long current_val = products[index - 1];
    Prod best;
    long long minval;
    int max_size = 0;
    while (index < n) {
        if (candidates.empty()) {
            minval = max_val;
        } else {
            best = candidates.top();
            minval = best.p;
        }
        if (minval <= prod_simple) {
            candidates.pop();
            long long new_product = minval * (best.last + 1);
            if (new_product < max_val) {
                candidates.push ({new_product, best.last + 1});
            }
        } else {
            minval = prod_simple;
            long long new_product = prod_simple * (rank_simple + 1);
            if (new_product < max_val) {
                candidates.push ({new_product, rank_simple + 1});
            }
            prod_simple = (long long) rank_simple * (rank_simple + 1);
            rank_simple++;
        }
        if (minval > current_val) {
            products.push_back(minval);
            current_val = minval;
            index++;
        }
        int size = candidates.size();
        if (size > max_size) max_size = size;
    }
    
    if (n <= 20) print (products, "Products: ");
    std::cout << "max heap size = " << max_size << std::endl;
    return minval;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cout << "Enter n: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ans = consecutive_products (n);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "duration = " << duration << " micro-s" << std::endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, `std::priority_queue<>` uses a `std::vector<>` as container by default (not a `std::queue` as you write in first sentence). And `std::priority_queue<>` might or might not be implementing a min-heap. I think the standard leaves that unspecified.

Comment: Thanks. For `std:dequeue` effectively, my mistake. Corrected. In the definition of the `priority_queue`, I explicitely mention that the container is a `std::vector`. Concerning the `heap`aspect, I was thinking of the cppreference site indication: *Working with a priority_queue is similar to managing a heap in some random access container,* So, it is similar to a min-heap from the functionality point of view, if I am not wrong. What is important is to have fast access to the min value. I was not refering to a particular internal implementation. @BitTickler

Answer (score 0):

```
import heapq


def factorial(x):
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1, x + 1): 
        fact *= i
    return fact


def nth_number(k):
    heap = [(2, 1, 2)]
    heapq.heapify(heap)
    size_fact = 2
    cur_factorial = factorial(size_fact)
    cur_number = -1
    i = 1
    while i <= k:
        x_number, start_from, size = heapq.heappop(heap) 
        if x_number > cur_number:
            if x_number == cur_factorial:
                # Insert the next factorial as well
                size_fact += 1
                cur_factorial = factorial(size_fact)
                heapq.heappush(heap, (cur_factorial, 1, size_fact)) 
            cur_number = x_number
            i += 1
        heapq.heappush(heap, (x_number / start_from * (start_from + size), start_from + 1, size))

    return cur_number


# Test the function
print(int(nth_number(4)))  # Output the 10th number in the sequence
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).